# using calloc to allocate matrix 4 rows and 7 bytes in each row

Tags: c

Is there something wrong with the code below to allocate matrix 4X7?

```
char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, 7);


for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
    imd[i] = (char*)calloc(7, sizeof(char));

//then free allocated memory as below

for (i=0; i<4; i++)
     free(imd[i]);

free(imd);
```

Comment: `4,7` --> `4, sizeof *imd` . The "row" is actually a pointer to where the row is going to be stored, you need to allocate space for 4 pointers

Comment: `char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, 7);` What's up with that?

Comment: could you please modify it on my example?

Comment: `char **imd = calloc(4, sizeof *imd);`  Using `sizeof` on the target is more robust than repeating type info, and [get rid of the bogus cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to actually allocate a true 2D array instead of what you are currently doing. What you have here is a pointer-based lookup table fragmented all over the heap. You also have pointless casts of the result from calloc. It seems likely that this code needs to rewritten from scratch, if you truly want to allocate a 2D matrix.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc/calloc! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to allocate memory for 4 rows. Each row is a single pointer. But you are allocating memory for

```
char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, 7); // Bug
```

Where `calloc(4, 7)` have no meaning at all. so try the following fix-

```
char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, sizeof(char *)); // Fix


for (i=0; i < 4; i++)
imd[i] = (char*)calloc(7, sizeof(char));

//then free allocated memory as below

for (i=0; i<4; i++)
 free(imd[i]);

free(imd);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, 7);
```

to

```
char** imd = (char**)calloc(4, sizeof(char*));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `calloc` in that way, you're not asking for 4 `char *`s, each of which can point to an area of memory of size 7, you're asking for 4 elements, which are each 7 bytes.

What you want to do is:

```
char ** imd=(char **)calloc(4,sizeof(char *));
```

Which will give you a region of memory, zeroed, with room for four `char *`s.

The code you have right now might work, assuming `sizeof(char *)<=7`, but it shouldn't be considered correct, so there is "something wrong" with it.

Comment: yes, it was working on my test system but on other one no...

Comment: You probably went between a 32 bit system (where the size of a pointer is 4 bytes, i.e. less than or equal to 7) to a 64 bit system (where the size of a pointer is 8 bytes, i.e. greater than 7).

Comment: thanks to everybody, it worked fine now. First time here, didn't even expect an answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char  (*imd)[7] = calloc(4, 7);//char imd[4][7];
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i < 4; ++i){
        for(j=0; j < 7; ++j){
            imd[i][j] = i * 16 + j;
            printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)imd[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(imd);
    return 0;
}
```